# What happens to an Activity and its public variables after Activity finishes?

Tags: android, android-activity

I am currently writing an Android application and I am new to Java and Android.

I am calling startActivity() starting an activity that has a number of public variables.  I am wondering what will happen to the values those public variables are assigned during the "onCreate" method after the activity finishes, and what happens to the instance of the Activity.

The activity finishes by calling a new Activity.

I am worried that this method of finishing an Activity will cause memory leaks and that I should be calling startActivityForResult() and calling the new Activity in the onActivityResult() function.

//Update
my activity is called like this:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, Example.class);
startActivity(i);
```

Advice?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

**Do not access Activity's variables directly**. To pass variables between activities use intents.

When starting activity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, NewActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("Extra1", "some string or something else");
// set more data
startActivity(intent);
```

When returning from activity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.putExtra("Extra1", "some string or something else");
//set data in intent as previous
setResults(RESULT_OK, intent)
finish();
```

Comment: I am starting an activity like this:

Intent i = new Intent(this, Example.class);
startActivity(i);

Comment: Ok, I guess my questions points to a somewhat flawed design.  I guess I am asking if I move around my app by starting a new Activity at the end of each Activity creating a path through my app that goes in a circle i.e. Activity1 calls Activity2 which calls Activity3 which calls Activity1 all by intents, what will happen to all the instances of the classes that I call?

Comment: Should I be letting the Activity end by dropping back to some master activity each time?

Comment: They will exist in the Activity stack, until you'll get out of memory, or until Android will decide to kill some of them.

Comment: So should I have a master class that handles passing the data back and forth?

Comment: If you are not planning on going back to previous activity, just set the appropriate flags in the intent (FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK and FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)

Comment: If you want to share data between all activities, either pass it in the intent, use shared preferences or extend Application to hold that data for you.

Comment: Cool that is pretty much what I am looking for.  But would a better design be to handle all of this from a single Activity at the "root" of the app?

Comment: I don't think so. In general you should access activities only when they are in foreground. They are not for sharing global data in any way.

Comment: Cheers for your help and Cheers for the quick reply. If I had enough reputation points id +1 your answer